# Product Attribute Magento 2 Cart Checkout don't show

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, product-attribute

In my checkout cart I got 2 attributes color and Talla but only work color,

[image]

In the admin the attribute talla is working

[image]

When I debug the phtml app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

I got this information about attributes

[image]

I search this atributes in eav_attribute_option_value and does't exits in talla option_id, the atribute talla has other option_id

Any idea to solve in this situation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create the **catalog_attributes.xml** file at below path:

Path : **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="your_attribute_id"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

In **app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/ Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml** use like this:

```
<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('your_attribute_id');?>
```

**For Configurable product in phtml file**

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();  
$customAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Your_Attribute_Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);  
echo $customAttribute;
```

Comment: @mandani Thank for answer, i try, but is configurable product in this case doesn't work. Do you know how to work this case with configurable product ?

Comment: @danielruedaa answer is updated..